# Error: "To upload an android app bundle you must be enrolled in app signing by google play"

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I am getting this error while uploading one of the client app(first vesrion) on google play store. Please help me why i am getting this error. I have followed all the steps to generate .aab file. But google console continuously raise upload error. Here can anyone tell me which I am missing while uploading the app.

Comment: There's an option in Google Play Console to enrol in app signing.  This is needed when using app bundles as play store dynamically creates/signs apk for particular user's device.

Comment: Yes there is option app signing. But there is message  "You should upload an APK to enroll into App Signing by Google Play. Go to App releases."

Comment: I am uploading first version of app. Is this error occurs at first time upload or next upload?

Answer (score 5):

For the new google play console you have to go to App -> Setup -> App integrity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to google play console and click on your application which you create for publish on the left panel click on app release option and just enabled this option "Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)" [image: screenshot for better understanding]

Comment: the design of Google Play console, any ideas where can I find this "Let Google manage and protect..." in the new console?

Answer (score 0):

In the new console:

Setup > App Integrity > App signing

[image]